# Playframework! Using @select for a Enum property

Tags: validation, select, combobox, enums, playframework

I'm trying to create a @select input for a enum field. Everything works fine until the form is submitted. It fails with a weird validation error -> "error.invalid"

here's my code

Enum class

```
package model;
...
public enum UserType {

    UserType_Admin("Administrator"), UserType_Monitor("Monitor"), UserType_Audit("Audit");
    private String desc;

    private UserType(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Messages.get(desc);
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return toString();
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public static Map<String, String> options() {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for (UserType ut : UserType.values()) {
            Integer o = ut.ordinal();
            options.put(o.toString(), ut.desc);
        }
        return options;
    }
}
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
...
    @Id
    public Long                      userID;
    public UserType                  user_type;
}
```

Scala template

```
@form(routes.Users.save(userID)) {
   @select(
      userForm("user_type"),
      options(model.UserType.options),
      '_label -> Messages("UserType"), '_default -> Messages("choose_user_type"),
      '_showConstraints -> true
    )
}
```

on the controller the Save method:

```
 public static Result save(Long userID) {
        Form<User> userForm = form(User.class).bindFromRequest();
        if (userForm.hasErrors()) {   <- here it says that has errors
          return badRequest(useredit.render(new Session(session()), userID,
         userForm, new User()));
        }
  ...
}
```

if I inspect the userForm variable, I get:

> Form(of=class model.User, data={user_type=0}, value=None,
>   errors={user_type=[ValidationError(user_type,error.invalid,[])]})

The field user_type has the correct value,  0 if I choose the first item, 1 for the second, etc.

[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yy51olpiarkox7m/enum.png)

Anyone has a clue or a workaround for this? Maybe disable validation for this field? Tks guys

Comment: Problem solved. My solution was to change the field type to Integer and declare a new member called user_type_type just to have acess to the enum type.  
The model looks like this:  
@@Entity  
    public class User extends Model {
    ...
        @Id<br/>
        public Long               userID;
        public Integer            user_type;
    
        public UserType user_type_type() {
            if (user_type == null)
                return null;
            else
                return UserType.values()[user_type];
        }
    }